# My Macbook can't send out OPTIONS request anymore

Tags: networking, http

I guess this is a rare issue since I have googled the answer for days but seems like no one has run into this before. What happened is my computer could make OPTIONS requests out to remote servers without any problem before, but all of a sudden it can't anymore. The requests was "failed" or "aborted" in failure error. I checked the server's log and any other requests (GET, POST, PUT...) but the OPTIONS ones made it to the server.

- It's not a browser issue since I tried to send a request using Ruby code in irb.
- It's not my wifi issue because I tried it using different networks as well
- I turned off Firewall but it still doesn't work
- I "reset" the network settings on my computer and by this I mean I removed the "preferred" networks and added them again.
- I restarted the computer several times.

Can you recommend any other places I could look into to debug this network issue further?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a progrmaming question; voted to migrate to [SU]

Comment: my bad, i'll move it myself